# Separar cadena concatenada

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas noches a todos,

Estoy almacenando los eventos del mouse en un ListView, para posteriormente almacenarlos en una base de datos, pero tengo una cadena concatenada, esta quisiera poder separarla en dos partes ejemplo:
MouseButton - Left, separar la cadena en dos, MouseButton en la columna 0 y Left en la columna 1 del listBox en las columnas 2 y 3 estoy guardando datos que capturo de unos labels.

Ejemplo, en la columna Action quisiera obtener los datos despues del "-" Left, Down, Down Right y en la columna Mouse or Key dejar solo el evento MouseButton, Key Down, Key Up.

Agrego imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cada evento del Mouse tengo un código como este:

```
 public void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Clicks > 0)
            LogWrite("MouseButton - " + e.Button.ToString());//Esta seria la cadena a separar
    }

public void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite("KeyDown - " + e.KeyData.ToString());//Esta seria la cadena a separar
    }
```

Metodo para agregar los eventos en el ListView:

```
private void LogWrite(string txt)
    {
        lv = new ListViewItem(txt);
        lv.SubItems.Add(Environment.NewLine);
        lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_x.Text.ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_y.Text.ToString());
        listCapture.Items.Add(lv);
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que se me pueda brindar.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer eso con un `Split` del texto que le pasas a la función `LogWrite`, de la siguiente forma:

```
lv = new ListViewItem(txt.Split('-')[0].Trim()); //Separas la cadena por el carácter '-' en un array y obtienes la posición 0
lv.SubItems.Add(txt.Split('-')[1].Trim()); //Separas la cadena por el carácter '-' en un array y obtienes la posición 1
//El Trim es para eliminar el espacio que queda.
lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_x.Text.ToString());
lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_y.Text.ToString());
listCapture.Items.Add(lv);
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, estoy intentando adaptar tu código y me marca error en el ("-")
Error: CS1503 no puede convertir un String a Char
@Marc

Comment: Gracias @Marc al final quedo así:
private void LogWrite(string txt)
        {
            string[] lineItems = txt.Split('-');//Separas la cadena por el carácter '-'

            lv = new ListViewItem(txt);  //en un array y obtienes la posición 0
            lv.Text = lineItems[0]; // en un array y obtienes la posición 1
            lv.SubItems.Add(lineItems[1]); //El Trim es para eliminar el espacio que queda.
            lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_x.Text.ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_y.Text.ToString());
            listCapture.Items.Add(lv);
        }

Comment: @JDanielSolisV Modifico la respuesta añadiendo las comillas simples que se me pasaron.